# I cant populate a select

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, select

I have data to fill a select in Angular, I´m using a example I saw on inthernet but I can´t see anything on the html. Data in the future is going to come from a service, but I´m trying to use this harcoded data to test first.
Originally, the example was commming with a ngModel, but that was causing errors. So I tried to replace it with a formGroup, but I don´t now what to type in there.

```
     areas: Area = {
        id: 1,
        nombre: "Contabilidad"
      };
    
     onSelect(id: any): void{
        console.log('id ', id);
      }
    
<form class="theForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myForm">

    <br><br>
    <label >Area </label><br>
          <select [formGroup]="myForm." (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
              <option *ngFor="let area of areas" value={{areas.id}}>
                 {{areas.nombre}}
              </option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
```

errors:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function
```

The data from the service will be a collection of id, names

Comment: Your `areas` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

1. As @Arcteezy sias, `areas` is  not an Array. Change to

```ts
     areas: Area[] = [
      {
        id: 1,
        nombre: "Contabilidad"
      }
     ];
```

2. in the `ng-if`, you want to reference to to the item (`area`), not the whole Array (`areas`): `value={{area.id}}` and `{{area.nombre}}`.

Answer (score 0):

First, your TypeScript issues. Your array definition is wrong. You are creating an `object` not an `array`. So, your `areas` array should be:

```
areas: Area[] = [
    { id: 1, nombre: 'Contabilidad' },
    { id: 2, nombre: 'RRHH' },
    { id: 3, nombre: 'Finanzas' }
]
```

The Angular part. You are using [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), be sure to check that out first. **Your markup is wrong**. First, you should be creating a `myForm` object with the provided `FormGroup`/`FormBuilder` API and create a `nombreArea` FormControl:

```
...

import { FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

...

export class AreaComponent {

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ...

  myForm = this.fb.group({
    nombreArea: [null]
  });

  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

}
```

That said, your `select` must be a `FormControl`, not a `FormGroup`. Like this:

```
<select class="area-select" (change)="onSelect($event)" formControlName="nombreArea">
   <option value="" disabled>Seleccionar Area</option>
   <option *ngFor="let area of areas" [ngValue]="area.id">{{area.nombre}}</option>
</select>
```

This way, it should render a `select` element with a "default" option (Seleccionar Area), show the `area.name` and select as value the `area.id`

Reactive Forms are a little verbose, but once you get a grip on them they are very useful.